# How to stop my hp from increasing when i press hp up button and out of skillpoints

Tags: javascript

So i have a working function but its still going when i have 0 skill points
http://prntscr.com/ns4tfx   http://prntscr.com/ns4tld    http://prntscr.com/ns4tse          as you can see it keeps going up. it shouldn't do anything if skillpoints is at 0

I've tried messing around with if statements to fix it but no luck

Here's my Javascript code:

```
function HitPointsup(){
    if (SkillPoints>0 && rebirths >=1)  
        SkillPoints = SkillPoints - 1;
        HitPoints = HitPoints + 10;
        document.getElementById('SkillPoints').innerHTML = SkillPoints;
        document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;
```

Here's my html code:

```
 Skill Tree &nbsp; &nbsp; SP:<span id="SkillPoints1">0</span>
                <br />
                <br />
                <button id="HitPointsup" onclick="HitPointsup()">Hp 
up</button> &nbsp; <button id="SkillPoints2" onclick="Mp up()">Mp 
up</button>
                <br />
                <button id="SkillPoints3" onclick="Hp regen()">Hp 
regen</button>
                &nbsp;
```

I expect the hp up button to only work when i have skill points to spend ( i thought putting if(SkillPoints >0) would be enough). my acual results is you can keep pressing the button and hp keeps going up by 10. skill points stay at 0 tho no negative numbers there.

Comment: This is part of the basic rules in html: 2 elements can not have the same identifier. Here you have 3 times (id = "SkillPoints");
do not be surprised if the behavior of the page is out of control then !

Comment: i mean my code works fine that wasn't a issue. i changed it now. i was going through each of those and making a function. those 2-3 where the ones i had left. i just want my hp to stop increaseing so it makes sense in a upgrade system. it shouldn't increase when u have 0 skill points

Comment: `onclick="Mp up()"`  and `onclick="Hp regen()"` is also bad, if you expect good answers, you must post correct information

Comment: i didn't make those functions yet so those buttons dont work on purpose. Im not a professional at html or javascript im just starting up. how was i supose to know its correct to have no space's sorry ;/ the main point of the post was to post the one line showing my HitPointsup format

Comment: So you think we do not have to read what you post to understand what you are looking for?

Comment: @MisterJojo im sorry im new . ive posted parts of this html code a few other times and your the only one to comment on my buttons that im not working on yet. I will make sure to leave them out or comment them out in future questions

Comment: If you are new, get ready to meet more grumpy than me. You must correct your spaces so that I can withdraw my negative vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a 'single line if', that means that only the first line below the *if (SkillPoints>0 && rebirths >=1)* is being verified. The other values are getting updated as-well. Try to user brackets like:

```js
function HitPointsup(){
    if (SkillPoints>0 && rebirths >=1){  
        SkillPoints = SkillPoints - 1;
        HitPoints = HitPoints + 10;
    }
    document.getElementById('SkillPoints').innerHTML = SkillPoints;
    document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;
}
```

Comment: o wow thanks. i had no idea brackets were that important that makes a lot of sense thanks for clarification.

Comment: I'm glad it works. Can you please mark as the correct answer?

Comment: sorry new at this

Comment: thanks. Ive posted my htm stuff plenty of times. i basically copy pasted first line to make a lot of buttons then orginized them how i wanted them then changed the onclicks / what text was on the button. i really didnt think the id was important if my program works fine and i wasnt useing those buttons. now im working on the hp and mana regen buttons. i need to go back through and check correct answer